# In which case will MessageContext be null but PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage() is not null?

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I am new to Apache CXF. I am looking into some code to learn it. I find this is a common coding way:

```
HttpServletRequest request = null;
if (getMessageContext() != null) {
    request = (HttpServletRequest) getMessageContext()
            .getHttpServletRequest();
} else {
    if (PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage() != null) {
        request = (HttpServletRequest) PhaseInterceptorChain
                .getCurrentMessage().get("HTTP.REQUEST");
    }
}
```

I am wondering how can getMessageConext from the WebServiceContext injected by using annotation @Resource return null while PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage() doesn't? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, this code allows for both to be null. Why do you say `while PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage() doesn't`?

Comment: @Bentaye I mean in which case will this happen (getMessageContext() is null but PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage() is not null)?